# Display price from html drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a very basic html document with two drop downs. When specific values in the drop down menus are selected I would like it to display a certain price in a text area below.

I have the drop downs setup, but I can't find a way to show specific prices for the drop down selections.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my html.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="current">select</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select id="current" name="current" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="desired">select</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select id="desired" name="desired" class="form-control">
       <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript or jquery for that. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @memelords Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/amvL3hmx/) fiddle, is this what you want ?

Comment: you need to explain your question further mate. Are you trying to dynamically assign price values to your dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create text field with id is price

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $("#current").on('change',function(){
        $("#price").val($(this).val());
//                   you can see values in console also
               console.log("Price :"+$(this).val());

    });
});
```

try this one

Comment: I think I need to learn js before messing with this. Unless it is easier than it looks.

Comment: yes, its not so much hard, only any latest js include it. use  with selector id or class using # or . (dot)